# Understanding Sign extension

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
  unsigned int b;
  signed int a;
  char z=-1;
  b=z;
  a=z;
  printf("%d %d",a,b);
}
```

gives -1 -1.  why does no sign extension occur, ALSO, when does it occur?

Comment: "What is unisgned? –" : a typo obviously, since fixed. Humans usually exhibit better cognition.

Comment: It did occur.  If it didn't, you would have seen 255, 255.

Comment: @Hans: The idea that any 255 ever existed is confusing because it supposes a value model contrary to C's...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sign extension DID occur, but you are printing the results incorrectly.  In your printf you specified `%d` for `b`, but `b` is unsigned, you should have used `%u` to print `b`.

printf does not know the type of its arguments and uses the format specifies to interpret them.

```
printf("%d %u",a,b);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `printf` looks at the raw memory, not the type. use `%u` to print the value as unsigned.

See.

http://ideone.com/Qpcbg

Comment: To clarify: in C one cannot check the type of a variable (that's why we have different format specifiers for `printf`). An excellent list of format specifiers can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/).

Comment: `printf` does not "look at raw memory". It simply has UB if you pass the wrong argument types. For example on x86_64 the arguments will not be in memory, and if you pass a floating point type where an integer is expected, `printf` will not inspect the bits of the floating point value's representation and print them as an integer; it will just fail to see them at all.

Comment: Then how do you explain;    unsigned char z=-1;  printf("%u %d",z,z); giving the same output?

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined behaviour. If you do not see how this answers your question, please look up the words "undefined" and "behaviour" in the dictionary and meditate until it becomes clear.